# Problems adding native DLLS to Java runtime (JIntellitype)

Tags: java, netbeans, dll

I'm trying to get JIntellitype to function with my java application, but I am stuck at the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitypeException: Could not load JIntellitype.dll from local file system or from inside JAR
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.<init>(JIntellitype.java:114)
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.getInstance(JIntellitype.java:177)
    at marketbot.SettingsWindow.<init>(SettingsWindow.java:27)
    at marketbot.MarketBot$2.run(MarketBot.java:129)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: FromJarToFileSystem could not load DLL: com/melloware/jintellitype/JIntellitype.dll
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.fromJarToFs(JIntellitype.java:150)
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.<init>(JIntellitype.java:105)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.melloware.jintellitype.JIntellitype.fromJarToFs(JIntellitype.java:146)
    ... 18 more
```

I have the DLLs everywhere where they should be (honestly, I've put them every place I can imagine), and I still can't get it to work.  It worked earlier today, but after a computer restart, I now get this error again.

I use netbeans, so I added the JIntellitype JAR to the project libraries, and I have the DLLS in C:\Windows\System, main project folder, src folder, dist folder, lib folder, java jdk jre bin folder (where all the other dlls are), and nothing can seem to get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

In my google quests, I did come across https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/issues/detail?id=12&can=1&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary but I can't get that to help me at all.

Comment: You may want to provide the code that is trying to load the DLLs as well

Comment: I'm simply using the JIntellitype library...so there is no custom code running, just the example code basically: https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'm not entirely sure why, but I decided to install Java x64, switch my environment to 64-bit and use the 64 bit DLL and it now works perfectly.  I guess ~magic~ happened  :-/

Comment: What happened was is that when you work with native code your code isn't cross-platform compatible like java. So you must have been compiling or using a 64-bit DLL and then using a 32-bit java.

Answer (score 0):

I am the author.  Typically this means it can't find your DLL but have you tried just getting our example app working?  You can download the example here:

https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/downloads/list

Also are you using a 64 bit JVM?  If so you need to make sure you use the 64 bit Intellitype.DLL and rename it to JIntellitype.dll

Comment: Thanks for responding!  No, that example app doesn't work and fails with the same error.  If I try to manually load the DLL (since the JIntellitype.jar doesnt show the actual error message through its catches), i get an initialization error:  "        System.load("C:\\Users\\Christopher\\Desktop\\jintellitype-1.3.9-dist\\jintellitype-1.3.9\\JIntellitype.dll");"  yields "A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed", while doing the same loading the 64-bit version yields: "Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform". So something in the initialization of the dll is failing